# Sync function wraps Async operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, callback, promise

Say we have the following if statement

```
.
.
if (!user.comparePassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
    }
.
.
```

where `comparePassword(password)` is a function to check if the user input password is identical to the one in the database.., and it's in another module being defined as follows:

```
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (password) {
let match = false;

bcrypt.compare(password, this.password)
.then(function (isMatch) {
  if(isMatch){
    match = true;
  }
})
.catch(function (err) {
  // handle error
});
return match;
};
```

The problem is in I/O.., where one could easily see the `if` statement depends on a function `comparePassword(password)` that could finish execution before the promises inside it `bcrypt.compare()` finishes execution.., which means I get `match` most of the time `false` even if it should technically be `true`. the compare function of bcrypt runs an expensive operation, so how do I get the result of comparison in time without blocking code-execution ?

Comment: You cannot *get* the result. You have to wait, and only continue with the rest of your code when it's available.

Comment: but wouldn't that be horrible for other users' requests ?

Comment: I did not say you'd have to block for waiting. That's the magic of asynchrony/concurrency: other stuff can happen while you are waiting.

Comment: You cannot. The `return` needs to happen immediately, it cannot block until the result is available. You can however return the promise from the function, and then use `user.comparePassword(password).then(function(match) { if (match) { … } else {…} });`

Comment: Got it thank you for helping me out.